# How do I get the divs to show in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this script on dynamic radio buttons... On load the divs display, great. One is automatically checked, great. If I click the other radio button the divs hide, great. When I click back to the main radio button to show the divs again the divs don't reappear.

How do I get the divs to reappear (show)?????

```
 function hide() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("hideRow");
        var coup = document.getElementById("coup");
        if ("hideRow") {
            ele.style.display = "none";
            coup.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            ele.style.display = "block";
            coup.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your `if ("hideRow")` will always return true, so the `else` will never run. The `if` is checking if the string `"hideRow"` is true. It always is, so the `else` never runs. What is the `if` supposed to be checking?

Comment: Show the HTML. There is no reference to what checkboxes, what ele and coup are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try :

```
function hide() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("hideRow");
    var coup = document.getElementById("coup");
    if (ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        coup.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        coup.style.display = "block";
    }
}
```

Comment: OR the ele.style.display == "block" could (and possibly should depending on the rest of the code) be changed to something like ele.selected [I am sure this is not the right syntax, this is pseudo code for if ele is a selected radio button].

Answer (score 0):

This is always true:

```
if ("hideRow") {
    // Always executes
}
```

So, you only ever get to the if-block. You need to change the conditional on your if-statement.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (ele.style.visibility == 'visible';) {
        ele.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        coup.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    } else {
        ele.style.visibility = 'visible';
        coup.style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
```

I may have entirely missed the mark and not understood what your trying to do, but that's the way I'd do it (I think - you may be trying to do something else).